# Laravel Policies in API always 403 unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-passport, policy

I tried to authorize users in userController using Policies. I followed documentations and some tutorials and it doesn't seem to work anyways.

**api.php**

```
Route::resource('users', 'User\UserController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
```

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\UserCreated;
use App\Mail\UserEmailUpdated;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
class UserController extends ApiController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('can:view,user')->only('show');
    //$this->middleware('can:update,user')->only('update');
    //$this->middleware('can:delete,user')->only('destroy');
  }

    public function show(User $user)
    {
        //$this->authorize('view', $user);
        return $this->showOne($user);
    }
```

**UserPolicy.php**

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Traits\AdminPolicyTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, User $model)
    {
        //return $user->id === $model->id
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $policies = [
        App\User::class => App\Policies\UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Neither `$this->middleware` nor `$this->authorize` works. If I remove policy authorization from the controller, everything works fine. Also, I'm passing Personal Access token from Passport in the request and it works fine too. If I intentionally make a typo in the Policy file, the error gets thrown so the policy seems to be connected to the controller properly.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... unless you aliased the `App` namespace in your `AuthServiceProvider` you are referencing the wrong classes ... `App\User::class` would be referring to `App\Providers\App\User`, same for `App\Policies\UserPolicy::class`

Comment: I have app namespaces in every file, just haven't pasted them here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely referencing the wrong classes there. The namespace for `AutheServiceProvider` is declared as `App\Providers`. Unless otherwise aliased all references (that are not Fully Qualified Class Names) are referenced from this namespace that is declared.

```
App\User::class     would be   'App\Providers\App\User'
```

You will need to alias the `App` namespace, alias these classes or use their FQCN.

```
use App;
...
App\User::class
```

Or

```
use App\User;
...
User::class
```

Or

```
\App\User::class
```

Or - less preferred (use the string for the FQCN)

```
'App\User'
```

Comment: yep, that's the correct solution, thanks dude, I just assumed that the namespace is app and wasn't paying attention to that. thanks